# Does JQuery have a way to unbind events in random HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery to set the HTML inside a div.  Something like this:

```
$(div).html(strHtmlBlob);
```

strHtmlBlob is a chunk of HTML returned via Ajax from the server.  After, it's assigned, I set up some events for elements in the new HTML blob by doing this:

```
$(div).find("a").click(a_ClickHandler);
```

That all works perfectly fine.  The problem is REMOVING the events.  I want to make sure I clean up the DOM properly.

I'm removing the HTML like so:

```
$(div).html("");
```

But I can see that the events are still there.  Is there a way to clean up events for elements that no longer exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use .remove() instead of .html("")

That will clear the elements and events all at once.  JQuery does a lot of cleanup magic under the covers if you let it.

Comment: Er, why did you delete the contents of this answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(div).find('a').unbind('click');
```

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind#typefn).

Alternatively, you should [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) it:

```
$(div).empty();
```

According to the docs:

> Note that this function starting with 1.2.2 will also remove all event handlers and internally cached data.